# docker-compose does not see volumes changes in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm working with docker-compose.

My docker-compose.yml looks like

```
redis:
  image: redis
  expose:
      - "6379"
  volumes:
      - ./redis:/data

nerdzcrush:
  image: nerdzeu/docker-nerdzcrush
  ports:
      - "8181:81"
  links:
      - redis
  volumes:
      - ./mediacrush:/home/mediacrush
```

When I run `docker-compose up` everything works fine.

After that, I needed to change the mount path.
I stopped the containers with `docker-compose stop`, I changed my docker-compose.yml in this way:

```
redis:
  image: redis
  expose:
      - "6379"
  volumes:
      - ./nerdzcrush/redis:/data

nerdzcrush:
  image: nerdzeu/docker-nerdzcrush
  ports:
      - "8181:81"
  links:
      - redis
  volumes:
      - ./nerdzcrush/mediacrush:/home/mediacrush
```

And I removed the old directories with

```
sudo rm -rf ./mediacrush ./redis
```

After that, I started the containers wiht `docker-compose up -d`

I expect that the containers start to work with the new path, but I see that the old path are used. Thus I have again ./mediacrush and ./redis in my folder.

That's something I understood wrongly about docker-compose or that's an issue with docker-compose?

I'm using docker-compose version: 1.5.0dev

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's only supposed to preserve volumes if they are container data volumes (not host volumes like in your case).

I would try running `docker-compose rm` to remove the containers (after stopping them). After that the `up` should use the correct path.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did and everything works. But it is the correct behavior? It's documented somewhere? By the way, since your answer is what I did that's the accepted answer.

Comment: It's not well documented. I'm working on some docs for the next release

Comment: When you release the documentation please comment here or contact me somehow, I'll read it with pleasure.